# Prove that in a Hilbert space, $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \langle x_{n_k} , y\rangle =\langle x,y \rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $(x_n)_n$ a bounded sequence in $\mathscr H$.

How can I show that there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$  and an $x \in \mathscr{H}$ so that
$$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \langle x_{n_k},y\rangle= \langle x,y\rangle $$ 
for all $ y \in \mathscr{H} $?

I know some of such proofs, but I don't know how to show that for a Hilbert space ! As a hint I got : using the diagonal consequences argument.
Appreciate any help of you !

Comment: Do you know the Banach-Alaoglu theorem?

Comment: read about it, don't think I can use it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mentioned diagonalization I'll give you a (sketch of) proof that uses the method. For this proof to work, we need to assume also that $\mathscr H$ is **separable** though.

Let $E=\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathscr H$ (which exists by our assumption that $\mathscr H$ is separable). For each fixed $i\in\Bbb N$, the sequence $(a_n)_n$ defined by
$$
a^{(i)}_n:=\langle x_n,e_i\rangle
$$
is a bounded sequence in $\Bbb R$ (or in $\Bbb C$, depending on what's your base field), hence we can extract a subsequence $a^{(i)}_{n_k}\to a^{(i)}$. This corresponds to a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$.

Can you see now which diagonal sequence you should take so that $\langle x_{n_k},e_i\rangle$ converges for all $i\in\Bbb N$?

We know that $E$ is an orthonormal basis, what do you need to do to conclude that $\langle x_{n_k},y\rangle$ converges for all $y\in \mathscr H$?

---

**Edit**: Denote $(x^{(i)}_{n})_n$ to be the $i^{\text{th}}$ subsequence of $(x_n)_n$, i.e. we have $x^{(0)}_{n}=x_n$ and that $x^{(i+1)}_{k}=x^{(i)}_{n_k}$ be a subsequence of $x^{(i)}_{n}$.

Consider 
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    x^{(1)}_1 & x^{(1)}_2 & x^{(1)}_3 & \dots & \text{ a subseq. such that $a^{(1)}_{n_k} \to a^{(1)}$} \\
    x^{(2)}_1 & x^{(2)}_2 & x^{(2)}_3 & \dots & \text{ a subseq. such that $a^{(2)}_{n_k} \to a^{(2)}$}\\
    x^{(3)}_1 & x^{(3)}_2 & x^{(3)}_3 & \dots & \text{ a subseq. such that $a^{(3)}_{n_k} \to a^{(3)}$} \\
\vdots
    \end{matrix}
$$
we can define a diagonal sequence $x'_n:=x^{(n)}_n$. From construction, it is easy to see that $\langle x'_{n},e^{(i)}\rangle \to a^{(i)}$ for all $i\in\Bbb N$.

Thanks to the remark by Berci, actually my proof works for inseparable Hilbert space $\mathscr H$ as well. We just have to restrict our attention to the (separable) subspace $H:=\overline{\text{span}}\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ .

Comment: I thought every Hilbert Space has an Orthonormalbasis (Zorn's Lemma)? hmm not quite sure..but if I count $ n_1=x_n1$,$n_2=a_n1,....$ then maybe ${(n_i)}_i $ for all i ? For the second question, maybe using that for any Hlbert Space with Orthonormalbasis $S$ you can write $ v= \sum_{u \in S} <u,v>u $ for any $v \in H$?

Comment: Zorn's lemma gives you a Hamel basis, which is an entirely different object from an orthonormal basis. I don't understand your answer to the first question but your idea for the second one is right.

Comment: Perhaps you're right about every Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis. What I'm not certain is whether it is countable if $\mathscr H$ is not separable. You need the fact that $E$ is countable in order to use the diagonalization argument.

Comment: This proof works for a general Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, too: take the closure of the subspace generated by $(x_n)$ and apply the proof there.

Comment: thank you a lot @BigbearZzz. I think I see what you mean..but I  don't get what diagonal sequence has to be chosen

Comment: @constant94 I've edited the answer to add further details. Hope it helps.